# How to change SPF_admin password?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-account

We are using sharepoint 2010.

As we no longer remember the SPF_admin credentials, i want to reset password for that account. .

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010 it is easy.

- Reset the Password for SPF-ADmin account
- Then Go to Central Admin > Security > Managed Accounts
- On this Page edit the SPF-Admin account
- from here set the use the current password and enter the new password.
- click ok.
- It will take time( depends upon the number of server and services running under this account)
- Finally test it.

Comment: Use current password? https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B2CB25B9690C6E9!116&authkey=!AHB7-aIg8CkqTPU&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG

Comment: did you change the password?

Comment: I tried with use existing password it says username and pasword are not valid , when i try set new password value it says https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B2CB25B9690C6E9!117&authkey=!ALJD-dCAb66X3aE&v=3&ithint=photo%2cPNG but i tried alphanumeric.

Comment: you have to reset the password 1st on the domain then enter in the field of exisitng password

Comment: Ok thanx :D ill do that